# running total, Sum, over, order by not returning negitiive values

Tags: sql

I have a problem where my running total will not return negitive values for the net_qty.
My goal is to have a running total of quntity that will be used in the future to fullfill sales orders.
This running total named Net_Qty in my query only returns postive numbers. where I know for a fact that there should be a negitive balance agisnt orders submitted.
Here is the code.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Job.Job
    , Sales_Order
    , Material_Req.Material
    , Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty AS ON_Hand
    , Material_Req.Est_Qty
    , Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty - SUM(job.Order_Quantity)  OVER (order by Job.job ASC)  AS Net_Qty 
    , Material_Req.Lead_Days
    , Job.Sched_Start
    , Job.Status

FROM         Material INNER JOIN
                      Job INNER JOIN Material_Req 
             ON Job.Job = Material_Req.Job ON Material.Material = Material_Req.Material
                      INNER JOIN Job_Operation 
             ON Job_Operation.job = job.job
                      INNER JOIN Material_Location 
             ON Material_Location.Material = Material.Material
                      INNER JOIN SO_Detail
             ON SO_Detail.job = job.Job

WHERE     (Material_Req.Act_Qty <> Material_Req.Est_Qty) 
 AND Material.Material = '101291'
 AND job.Status = 'Pending' and job.sched_start >= GETDATE()

ORDER BY Net_Qty DESC
```

Results returned.
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olqcP.jpg)

I know that there should be another order for material 101291 calling for a Est_Qty of 40 on the sched_start date of 2022-10-05
Which should return a result with the Net_qty being -35

I'm not sure I can add tables of data here. I can answer questions about the data if you have some.

Thanks in advance for your help.
SQL version 15.0.2080.9

Comment: can you share sample input, current output and expected output tables?

Comment: @lemnon sorry I was reviewing it and the Net_Qty is also wrong. I'll have to delete the question and look at the SUM value again. as 225- 8 = 217 not 205 from the attached results... pulling the wrong field

Comment: Don't delete the question, just edit it. @Highstride